# Are there any published RPG adventures set in Utumno or Angband?

Tags: game-recommendation, published-adventures, middle-earth

Are there any published RPG adventures set in [Utumno](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Utumno) or [Angband](http://www.thangorodrim.net/what_is_angband.html), the the dungeon fortresses of Morgoth as described in J.R.R. Tolkien's works? Anything that's published is fine - say with the MERP, Decipher LOTR, or One Ring systems, or else a resource book not affiliated with a particular RPG.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the short answer is no. The most recent Tolkien games produced by Decipher and Cubical 7 focused on the later 3rd Age - the time of Bilbo and Frodo. ICE Middle Earth Role Playing was a bit earlier for their default campaign in the third age, but some of their adventures / campaign settings books had information in other eras too (sometimes 2nd age, like the Eregion book, sometimes 4th age).

Comment: Thanks Lynn - Come to think of it, there aren't any LOTR RPGs where the default setting takes place during the 1st and 2nd ages depicted in the Silmarillion, are there? Perhaps there are copyright issues with the Tolkien estate.

Comment: You might be right about licensing issues;  Stuff that's far outside the scope of LotR tends to be kept in the much, much tighter grip of Christopher Tolkien, rather than in the more income-centered clutches of the Saul Zaentz company.